# Akeneo 2.1.8 : Sending e-mail from console task does not follow configuration

Tags: php, command-line-interface, swiftmailer, akeneo

In Akeneo 2.1.8, I'm trying to send an e-mail in a console aware container like so:

```
$mailer = $this->getContainer()->get('mailer');
$message = $mailer->createMessage();
// generate message
$mailer->send($message);
```

However, it does not look like that the Akeneo configuration is used in this way. For example: my SMTP server runs at `localhost:1025`, but when I start debugging this code, it appears that `localhost:25` is used.

Am I missing something here? How can I use the mailer in a console command, while still using the Akeneo configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer to my own question. @Gaël, I already tried adding the configuration settings to my `parameters.yml` file:

```
parameters:
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: localhost
    mailer_port: 1025
    mailer_user: ~
    mailer_password: ~
```

But what I didn't do was add the port to the `config.yml` file:

```
swiftmailer:
    port: "%mailer_port%"
```

The weird part is: if I look at the original source code this line is there, but in my project this line was missing for reasons unknown. Fixed the `config.yml`-file and now everything works as expected.

Comment: You can accept this answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to use the default configuration 'localhost:25', like [here](https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/blob/5c185ff410fffbc16dea527a1e6dcae23eb7dfd3/app/config/pim_parameters.yml#L8)

You can overload it via the parameters.yml file https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/blob/2.2/app/config/parameters.yml.dist